# sql statement problem

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005

In my query I am trying to get yesterdays date and the exact same date on the selected year.
So today is 12/08/2010

I want 12/07/2010 and 12/07/2009

I forgot to mention the last person who created the database stored all the booked dates as intgers so basically

```
     Date  Year month booked  time
     28Sep09 2009 09 40084 1159
    07Oct09 2009 10 40093 1221
    08Oct09 2009 10 40094 1025
    16Oct09 2009 10 40102 1058
    02Nov09 2009 11 40119 1708
    05Nov09 2009 11 40122 1213
    13Nov09 2009 11 40130 1502
    24Nov09 2009 11 40141 1004
    24Nov09 2009 11 40141 1030
    16Feb10 2010 02 40225 1150
    16Feb10 2010 02 40225 1158
    08Mar10 2010 03 40245 1249
    05Apr10 2010 04 40273 0937
    24May10 2010 05 40322 1559
    25May10 2010 05 40323 1539
    04Jun10 2010 06 40333 1428
    26Jul10 2010 07 40385 1708
    19Aug10 2010 08 40409 1637
    02Sep10 2010 09 40423 0927
    03Sep10 2010 09 40424 1253
    13Sep10 2010 09 40434 1534
    04Oct10 2010 10 40455 1341
    19Oct10 2010 10 40470 0939
    02Nov10 2010 11 40484 0923
    03Nov10 2010 11 40485 0854
    03Nov10 2010 11 40485 1259
    08Nov10 2010 11 40490 1210
    12Nov10 2010 11 40494 1121
    18Nov10 2010 11 40500 1222
    05Aug10 2010 08 40395 1649
```

my dates look like that : (

so this would replace my last query

```
Declare @YearToget Integer 
Set @yearToGet = 2008

SELECT TOP (100) PERCENT DIVISION, SDESCR, 
      DYYYY, SUM(APRICE) AS Sales, SUM(PARTY) AS PAX, 
      SUM(NetAmount) AS NetSales, 
      SUM(InsAmount) AS InsSales, 
      SUM(CancelRevenue) AS CXSales, 
      SUM(OtherAmount) AS OtherSales, 
      SUM(CXVALUE) AS CXValue 
FROM  dbo.B101BookingsDetails AS B101BookingsDetails 
WHERE BOOKED <= DateAdd(year, @YearToGet - Year(getdate()), 
                 DateAdd(day, DateDiff(day, 1, getdate()), 0) )
  AND @YearToGet
GROUP BY SDESCR, DYYYY, DIVISION 
HAVING      (DYYYY = @YearToGet) 
ORDER BY DIVISION, SDESCR, DYYYY
```

Comment: I am trying to filter my dates, however they are stored as integers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
Declare @YearToget Integer 
Set @yearToGet = 2008

  Select DateAdd(year, @YearToGet - Year(getdate()), 
         DateAdd(day, DateDiff(day, 1, getdate()), 0) )
```

In your query:

```
   Where Booked = DateAdd(year, 2008- Year(getdate()), 
             DateAdd(day, DateDiff(day, 1, getdate()), 0) )
      Or Booked = DateAdd(year, 2009- Year(getdate()), 
             DateAdd(day, DateDiff(day, 1, getdate()), 0) )
      Or Booked = DateAdd(year, 2010- Year(getdate()), 
             DateAdd(day, DateDiff(day, 1, getdate()), 0) )
      Or Booked = DateAdd(year, 2011- Year(getdate()), 
             DateAdd(day, DateDiff(day, 1, getdate()), 0) )
```

Or

```
   Where Booked In
      (DateAdd(year, 2008- Year(getdate()), 
             DateAdd(day, DateDiff(day, 1, getdate()), 0) ),
       DateAdd(year, 2009- Year(getdate()), 
             DateAdd(day, DateDiff(day, 1, getdate()), 0) ),
       DateAdd(year, 2010- Year(getdate()), 
             DateAdd(day, DateDiff(day, 1, getdate()), 0) ),
       DateAdd(year, 2011- Year(getdate()), 
             DateAdd(day, DateDiff(day, 1, getdate()), 0) ) )
```

Your query above, rewritten:

```
Declare @YearToget Integer  
Set @yearToGet = 2008  
Select Division, SDESCR,        
    DYYYY, Sum(APRICE) Sales, 
    Sum(PARTY) AS PAX,        
    Sum(NetAmount) NetSales,        
    Sum(InsAmount) InsSales,        
    Sum(CancelRevenue) CXSales,        
    Sum(OtherAmount) OtherSales,        
    Sum(CXVALUE) CXValue  
From dbo.B101BookingsDetails 
Where Booked <= DateAdd(year, @YearToGet - Year(getdate()),                   
                DateAdd(day, DateDiff(day, 1, getdate()), 0) )      
-- AND @YearToGet -- This line appears to be incomplete
Group By SDESCR, DYYYY, Division
Having (DYYYY = @YearToGet)  
Order By Division, SDESCR, DYYYY
```

Comment: how could i implement this into my query, in the where statement

Comment: Just replace the @YearToget variable with the query parameter and use the entire expression (without the `Select' as you would a colun name or parameter.

Comment: check the query i wrote on top, please

Comment: Are the integers your dates are stored in equivilent to SQL server internal date values ? (gotten by running `DateDiff(day, 0, [SomeDate])` ? It loks like it, but the one you have listed, (`05Mar07`) should be `39144`, not `39146`....

Comment: yeah i dont now how i got the wrong number but 05Mar07 is 39146

Comment: I did, and included it in my answer... But PLEASE, think about formatting your sql to make it more readable.  Methinks part of your problem is it is very diificult to discern the structure and meaning of the sql when it's formatted poorly.

Comment: go it i needed a convert to int

Comment: i don't know why the days are messed up, but the data is matching very closely, i am going to try and subtract another day and see if it matches yesterdays

Comment: hmm it seems that the data is a little high by a day or wo but when i try subtracting a day the data stays the same : /

Comment: What are you trying to do exactly? You want the booked value to be on or before this same date in 2008 ?  Are all booked values stored as midnight ? or do they contain time values as well ?

Comment: thank you for continuing to help me, most people would have given up i appreciate it

Comment: your answer gets me the closest, i dont know why at times it is off my one or 2 passangers, but it has to do with the way the other database is set up

Answer (score 1):

A couple of notes. First, you should not use "TOP 100 PERCENT". It provides no benefit. If you are trying to use this in a View, you should know that using TOP 100 PERCENT with an ORDER BY will not guarantee the order when querying against the View. Second, it would appear that you have a problem with your integer values in that they are off by two days compared to `DateDiff(d,0, <date>)`. I have compensated for that in the Where clause with `BD.Booked = N.DateInt - 2` but you should look into the reasons why this is the case.

```
Declare @YearToGet int
Set @YearToGet = 2008

;With RawData As
    (
    Select 39503 As Booked
    Union All Select 39509
    Union All Select 39535
    Union All Select 39620
    Union All Select 39791
    Union All Select 39838
    Union All Select 39899
    Union All Select 39134
    Union All Select 39139
    Union All Select 39139
    Union All Select 39140
    Union All Select 39146
    Union All Select 39146
    Union All Select 39146
    )
    , Numbers As 
    (
    Select 0 As Value, Year(GetDate()) As [Year]
        , Cast( DateDiff(d,0,GetDate()) as datetime ) As [Date]
        , DateDiff(d,0,GetDate()) As [DateInt]
    Union All 
    Select Value + 1, [Year] - 1
        , DateAdd(yyyy, -1, [Date])
        , DateDiff(d, 0, DateAdd(yyyy, -1, [Date]))
    From Numbers
    Where Value <= ( Year(GetDate()) - @YearToGet )
    )
Select DIVISION, SDESCR, DYYYY
    , SUM(APRICE) AS Sales
    , SUM(PARTY) AS PAX
    , SUM(NetAmount) AS NetSales
    , SUM(InsAmount) AS InsSales
    , SUM(CancelRevenue) AS CXSales
    , SUM(OtherAmount) AS OtherSales
    , SUM(CXVALUE) AS CXValue
From dbo.B101BookingsDetails As BD
    Join Numbers As N
        On Cast(N.[Year] As char(4)) = BD.DYYYY
Where BD.Booked = N.DateInt - 2
Group By DIVISION, SDESCR, DYYYY
```

Comment: I think he wants to select it, not include it in his `WHERE` clause

Comment: @Abe Miessler - You could be right, although the original example is using it in the Where clause (perhaps incorrectly) implying he is attempting to filter the results. Tough to know without clarity.

Comment: Who knows what he wants. It's definitely a confusing question.

Comment: Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Procedure test, Line 53
Incorrect syntax near 'DYYYY'.

this is going to drive me nuts

Comment: @MyHeadHurts - What is the data type of the column `DYYYY`? Is it an integer or a string?

Comment: it is a char(4), i didn't create these tables

Comment: @MyHeadHurts - Then it is possible that it doesn't like the comparison of an integer to a char. I've revised the query to cast the Year value from the CTE.

Comment: i got the query to work but it isnt returning the correct values it is only returning one value

Comment: @MyHeadHurts - In the data you provided, which I mimicked in a CTE but you would obviously exclude that in the real query, only one of the values is even close to 08-Dec (39791) but not exact. Even fudging by two days I still get 09-Dec for that value.

Comment: hmm how can i use this to actually return data from the b101bookingdetails

Comment: @MyHeadHurts - It would help if you edit your post to show us the date that the given integer is supposed to represent. That would help us confirm that the algorithm used to convert a date to an integer (DateDiff less two days) is accurate.

Comment: i added examples of how my booked column looks

Answer (score 1):

yesterday

```
convert(varchar, getDate()-1, 101)
```

a year ago from yesterday

```
convert(varchar, dateadd(year, -1, getDate()-1), 101)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select getdate() /* Today */
select dateadd(day, -1, getdate()) /* Yesterday */
select dateadd(year, -1, dateadd(day, -1, getdate())) /* 1 year ago yesterday */
```